# wicked_pdf table sem borda ou contorno

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

No ambiente de desenvolvimento eu uso o Windows. logo faço a chamada em `config/initializers/wicked_pdf.rb` diretamente no arquivo .exe

dessa forma

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  exe_path: 'C:/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe'
}
```

Mas para produção uso ubunto. e logo uso a gem "gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'"
e modifico a chamada no wiked_pdf.rb para fazer referência, da seguinte maneira:

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  exe_path: Gem.bin_path('wkhtmltopdf-binary', 'wkhtmltopdf')
}
```

No entando, quando faço uso no windows, com o exe. ele monta o arquivo pdf com as tabelas organizadas.
já quando troco para chamada no ubunto com a gem wkhtmltopdf . ele da o problema de não reconhece as bordas das tabelas por algum motivo, já fiz várias tentativas diferentes, mas não obtenho sucesso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta gem que tu está utilizando contém a versão antiga do wkhtmltopdf.

Já tentou utilizar esta gem?
***wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge***
https://github.com/pallymore/wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge

Dai:
    WickedPdf.config = { exe_path: Gem.bin_path('wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge', 'wkhtmltopdf') }

Comment: Essa também me ajudou, no entanto o problema com o modelo antigo, para mim, funcionou inserindo >> 
gem 'bootstrap-sass' << no gemfile! resolveu também. Mas muito obrigado pela ajuda.